# How do I asynchronously define aliases or variables in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

With a django project, you get a script called `manage.py`, which has a bunch of subcommands such as `runserver`, `migrate`, etc.  You can get a list of them all by running the script with no arguments.

My plan is to parse that output, and use it to power TAB completion after `. manage.py`, and also set up aliases, so I can just type `migr[TAB]` instead of `./manage.py migrate`.

My problem is that because it's Python, *and* it needs to load in all the django machinery to show the subcommands, I'm waiting about a half second every time, on a really small project.  The larger the project, the longer it takes.

My idea was to run the interrogation of the script, definition of aliases, and setup of autocompletion, in a background task a la

```
(for subcommand in parse_manage_py; do alias $subcommand='./manage.py $subcommand'; done) &
```

But that doesn't set any variables in the parent shell.  I mucked around with `export` for a while before I figured out that exports "downwards" instead of "upwards".

Comment: Since `migrate.py` should have a fixed number of subcommands, why don't you define the aliases statically?

Comment: You can add management commands yourself.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/  I _could_ go and parse everything myself in bash, but that seems terrible.

Answer (score 0):

One (inelegant) approach could be to redirect the output of an asynchronous process (that does the slow work) to a file and use the content of that file only when you first need it. You can do things in the meantime. For instance:

```
# placing everything into a function only because it easier to test
function func {
    # Test (I think that "runserver" is one of the alias you should get)
    echo -n "start: "
    alias -p|grep -q runserver && \
        echo \"runserver\" is defined || \
            echo \"runserver\" is NOT defined

    # prepare the aliases in background
    f=$(mktemp)
    ( python ./manage.py | \
          sed -n 's/^    \(.*\)/alias \1=".\/manage.py \1"/p'
      sleep 2  # simulate slow process
    ) >$f &
    slow_process_id=$!

    # here you can do things...
    echo "I'm doing thing..."
    sleep 1
    echo "...finished my things. Waiting for the aliases"

    # but if you need the aliases you must check that they are ready
    wait $slow_process_id
    source $f
    rm -f $f
    echo "Aliases ready :-)"

    # Test again
    echo -n "end: "
    alias -p|grep -q runserver && \
        echo \"runserver\" is defined || \
            echo \"runserver\" is NOT defined
}
```

Please see also `coproc ... command ...`, but I think its filehandles disappear when the command it terminated.

---

I've also tried two **wrong** approaches: first I tried to have my
script `source` some alias definitions from a subprocess, but, of
course these aliases did not make to the calling shell.  The problem
here is that `&` spawns a subshell.

Then I tried to use indirection.  The problem here is that "indirect"
variables are not special and they are separated from the calling
shell.

Thanks G-Man for the useful comments.

Comment: You haven’t tried this, have you?

Comment: you're right, sorry. I had the aliases in my shell from previous experiments. Should I delete the post?

Comment: It’s your decision.  If I discover that an answer I have posted is fundamentally flawed and unrecoverable, I often delete it — although sometimes I leave it there, so people can see that that approach has been tried and led to a blind alley.  On the other hand, you seem to have made some progress in coming up with answers that *do* work — although, on the third hand, I don’t see exactly how your `mktemp` solution is any better that the original `. manage.py`, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  since you still leave the user’s terminal (and shell) unusable until the long-running process is done. (Also, `if [[ -n "$(cat $f)" ]]` is a terrible way to check whether the long-running process is done; all it does is check whether the process has written *any* output, and you can do that more simply with `-s "$f"`.) Do you want to try to improve on that?  Do you believe that you can devise a working solution based on `coproc`? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you don’t delete the answer, I would suggest that you clean up the bottom half.  The question isn’t about process substitution, here documents, indirect variables, or `eval`, so there’s no real point in talking about them if they don’t lead to an answer.  It might be useful to leave the statement that you tried `. manage.py &` and it didn’t work (and explain why), and leave it at that.  I’ll withdraw my downvote and let you decide.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  One other note: even though you joined [SU] nearly five years ago, you’re still a junior member in the sense that you’ve had very little activity (AFAICT, this is only your second answer on this site).  There are vague rumors floating around that new users [can be punished for deleting too many of their posts (although that probably refers specifically to negatively scored posts)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/271976#86998 "What can I do when I get “We are no longer accepting answers”?").  So it might be best for you to improve this answer as much as you can, and leave it.